# Why local storage not persisting after page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

The button text 'completed' should persist after browser refresh based on whether var item is true (after button click). I am not sure what the issue is but I have tried Chrome as well so I don't think it is browser related.

```
<template>
<button type="button" v-bind:class="order_button_style" @click="on_order_button_click()">
  {{ buttonText }}
</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {


item: '',
data() {

  return {
  item2: this.item
  }
},
methods: {
on_order_button_click() {
 this.item2 = true;
  localStorage.setItem(this.item2);
}

},
mounted() {
const storedState = localStorage.getItem(this.item2) === 'false';
if (storedState) {
  this.item2 = storedState;
}
},
computed: {
buttonText() {
  return this.item2 === true ? "Completed" : "Complete";
},
order_button_style() {
  return this.item2 === true
    ? "btn btn-danger"
    : "btn btn-primary";
}

}

};
</script>
```

Comment: You're never setting a value in `localStorage`. `setItem` takes 2 params, the name and the value, you're just setting the value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

I believe you meant to write `localStorage.setItem('item', this.item2)` and `localStorage.getItem('item')`

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to have solved the persist problem. I am refreshing the browser and button color and text just reset to the original state where item = ''

Comment: See my answer below, the `if` block in `mounted` will never run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage.setItem` takes 2 params, `name` and `value`.

I believe you meant to write the following:

Setting an item in `localStorage`

`localStorage.setItem('item', this.item2)`

and retrieving it

`localStorage.getItem('item')`

A few comments on other parts of your code:

- `this.item2 === true` can be shortened to `this.item2` if `item2` can never be anything other than a boolean.
- You're currently only using the value from `localStorage` if it's `false`, which it will never be because you're only ever calling `setItem` with a value of `true`
- I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `item` prop in the top level of the object
- Strongly consider using camelCase for your method names. Follow global conventions

UPDATE:

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
on_order_button_click() { // Should probably rename this to `onOrderButtonClick`, the current method name hurts to look at
  this.clickedOrderButton = true;
  localStorage.setItem('clickedOrderButton', this.clickedOrderButton);
}


created() {
  this.clickedOrderButton = localStorage.getItem('clickedOrderButton') === "true";
}
```

I've renamed `item2` to `clickedOrderButton`. I have no idea why you'd name that variable `item2` based on the code that is shown.

There's also no need to check whether `clickedOrderButton` is `true` before assigning it to `clickedOrderButton`, as it will resolve to `false` if it's not present (or intentionally set to something other than `true`) in `localStorage`.

Lastly, I've replaced `mounted` by `created`. As you're not accessing any DOM elements, there's no need to wait until the component is mounted to run that code

UPDATE#2:

If you have several instances of this component, you'll need to set use a different name than `clickedOrderButton`. You can use a unique identifier per button, which you can pass as a prop from above.

E.g.

```
props: {
  id: { type: String, required: true }
}
...
localStorage.setItem(`clickedOrderButton-${this.id}`, this.clickedOrderButton);
...
localStorage.getItem(`clickedOrderButton-${this.id}`);
```

Comment: My code currently looks like this, can you please have a look, it still doesn't behave as expected

Comment: methods: {
    on_order_button_click() {
     this.item2 = !this.item2;
      localStorage.setItem('itemName', this.item2);
    }
    
  },
  mounted() {
    const storedState = localStorage.getItem('itemName');
    if (storedState) {
      this.item2 = storedState;
    }
  }

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept this as the answer as the button does hold state now. However it does change the button state for every single task's button in the list after the page reload

Comment: Made another update to my answer for that. This happens because every component instance shares the state of `localStorage.clickedOrderButton`

Comment: No luck with the second update I'm afraid. I have an id column in my database so that should pass through the id but for some reason all the tasks are updated when I click the button

Comment: I'm gonna have to see the rest of your code in that case, hard to say what could be going wrong with just a description

Comment: solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140046/why-local-storage-is-changing-every-entry-in-task-list/62140174#62140174

Comment: Yeah that's basically the same thing I added to my answer